# What does the "D" mean in SQL syntax?

Tags: sql-server

Piotr Kononow's post [List all indexes in SQL Server database](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-indexes-in-the-database) contains an example of SQL query to list all indexes in a SQL Server database. And we have confirmed in testing that the example works indeed.

To fully understand the query, we have a question regarding the below `cross apply` section, please also refer to the full query included in the details at the end.

```sql
  cross apply (
    ...
  ) D (column_names)
```

**Our Question:**

What does it mean by the `D` and `D (column_names)`?

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Details: the full sample SQL query:**

```sql
--Reference:
--  https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-indexes-in-the-database

select
    i.[name] as [index_name]
  , substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns]
  , case
      when i.[type] = 1 then 'Clustered index'
      when i.[type] = 2 then 'Nonclustered unique index'
      when i.[type] = 3 then 'XML index'
      when i.[type] = 4 then 'Spatial index'
      when i.[type] = 5 then 'Clustered columnstore index'
      when i.[type] = 6 then 'Nonclustered columnstore index'
      when i.[type] = 7 then 'Nonclustered hash index'
      else 'ERROR'
    end as [index_type]
  , case
      when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
      else 'Not unique'
    end as [unique]
  , '['+schema_name(t.schema_id)+'].['+t.[name]+']' as [table_view]
  , case
      when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
      when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
    end as [object_type]
from
  sys.objects t
  inner join sys.indexes i
    on t.object_id = i.object_id
  cross apply (
    select
      col.[name]+', '
    from
      sys.index_columns ic
      inner join sys.columns col
        on ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id
    where
      ic.object_id = t.object_id
      and ic.index_id = i.index_id
    order by key_ordinal
    for xml path ('')
  ) D (column_names)
where
  t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
  and index_id > 0
order by i.[name]

;
```

Comment: It's just a virtual name for the result of the apply operator. You can use whatever name you want.

Comment: When in doubt consult [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) `[ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ , ...n ] ) ]`

Comment: Side note: this query is using `for xml` for aggregation, but it's not doing XML unescaping. It should be `select ', ' + col.name` and `for xml path (''), type)` and `, stuff(column_names, 1, 2, '') as [columns]`. Or on newer versions of SQL Server, just use `STRING_AGG`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does it mean by the D and D (column_names)?

`D` represent as a table alias while the `column_names` is for column alias for `col.[name]+', '`.

The `column_names` was used on SELECT list: `substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns]`

To learn more about apply operator I'd recommend to read these links: [link 1](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1) and [link 2](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-2).